# Cassandra Range Query

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, cassandra-2.1

I have a set of products (product_Id, price).

'Price' of all products keep on changing and hence need to be updated very frequently.

I want to perform range query on prices:

```
select * from products where price > 10 and price < 100;
```

Please note - I want to get the products in range. Query do not matter.

What is the best possible way to model this scenario? I'm using cassandra 2.1.9.

Answer (score 2):

If your price is a column key, you can only create range queries with your partition key. E.g.

Your table:

```
products (product_Id text, price float, PRIMARY KEY(productId, price))
```

Your range query:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE productId = 'ysdf834234' AND price < 1000 AND price > 30;
```

But I think this query is really useless. If you need ranges for your prices and without your partition key, you need a new table. But I think a Cassandra table with 2 columns is a bad database design. In your usecase a pure key value storage is a better option. (Like Redis) But you can also add productType, productVariation, productColor, productBrand ... as columns. In this case Cassandra is a good option for you. Then you can create tables like:

```
productsByType_price PRIMARY KEY(productType, productPrice, productId)
productsByType_color PRIMARY KEY(productType, productColor, productId)
productsByType_brand PRIMARY KEY(productType, productBrand, productId)
```

etc.

One tip: Read a bit more about how cassandra manages the data. This really helps you with your data modelling.